# C# Trying to parse excel file from webpage with login and pass. In the response excel content is absent

Tags: c#, html, .net, excel

I'll try parse content of the excel file which displayed on the webpage of confluence.[how to view page with excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c59lb.png).
But in the response there are not content of excel file.
[how to view response page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivrhS.png).
In html, excel file looks like table "tr-td".
How can a get it?
I haven't access to excel file on the server, only by web.

There is code:

```
string data;
            
var baseAddress = new Uri("https://test.com/");
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{

    Dictionary<string, string> userData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["os_username"] = "login",
        ["os_password"] = "pass@!"
    };
    HttpContent contentForm = new FormUrlEncodedContent(userData);
    using var response = await client.PostAsync("/dologin.action", contentForm);
    string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


    var result = await client.GetAsync("https://test.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7768346");
    data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

return data;
```

Comment: Excel is a program that can display various different types of data. Do you know the excel content in what kind of format it is csv, xls, xlsx....? Or maybe it looks like excel but it is actually an html code

Comment: On the webpage it is actually in html code. But question is why content not loading to page? Webpage has link to download this file, there it is in a xlsx format.

Comment: So which url is your get request, the "html page" or the "xlsx document" ;) ?

Comment: It is html page in the get request.

Comment: here is it looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/c59lb.png, 
here is webpage looks like in get request in Visual Studio i.stack.imgur.com/ivrhS.png

Comment: If you are getting an html then you would expect an html to be the return of result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Comment: If you can inspect the page requests, and see if there is another call which is specific only for the data - then use that one in the client.GetAsync